# Bash: How to get a specified line from a multi line string?

Tags: bash, shell

As the following example:

```sh
#! /bin/bash

usbId=$(lsusb | cut -d ' ' -f 6)
```

the `$usbId` is a multi line string which contains all usb devices on my computer. And I want to pick-up one of these line. Just like:

```sh
echo ${usbId[1]} # Don't work
```

In what way I can do that?

Thanks!

Comment: `usbId="$(lsusb | cut -d ' ' -f 6)"; echo "$usbId"`

Comment: `usbId=$(lsusb | while read a b c d e id rest; do echo $id; done | sed -n -e "2p")` if you want just the second id

Comment: IFS=$'\r\n' GLOBIGNORE='*' command eval 'array=($(lsusb))';echo "${array[1]}"|awk '{print $6}' 
This one liner will push all the usb data into an array called array and give you value number 1 from the array ; for other values change the number value in the array

Comment: @Inian, thanks for reply. I just want one line of the multi line string.